# shell script on node.js

Tags: node.js, shell

I am very new to node.js, 
I am trying to create a node.js script with the execution of shell script in it.

Here is the code which i have .

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn
var _ = require('underscore');
var deploySh = spawn('sh', [ 'vij.sh' ], {
  cwd: process.env.HOME + '/u/qa/gv/node/scripts',
  env:_.extend(process.env, { PATH: process.env.PATH + ':/usr/local/bin' })
});
```

and when i try to execute it, i am facing the below issue. Can anyone help me on this?

```
node vijay

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `/bin/sh` instead of `sh`?

Comment: You can drop `sh` and use `spawn('vij.sh')` - make sure that vij.sh has `#!/bin/sh` as the first line.

Comment: Hi, I have the #!/bin/sh at the first line. I modified the spawn but i get the same issue.

Comment: Hi Henk, yes i tried /bin/sh instead of sh, its the same error.

Answer (score 1):

spawn is complaining that it can't find 'sh', use 'bash' instead (you might also need to specify the full path to your script depending on your env setup.)

so I'd try:

1. spawn('bash', ['vij.sh'], ...
2. spawn('bash', ['/my/path/to/vij.sh'], ...
3. spawn('/my/path/to/vij.sh', [], ...

Answer (score 0):

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn
var _ = require('underscore');
var deploySh = spawn('sh', [ 'vij.sh' ], { 
  // cwd: process.env.HOME + '/u/qa/gv/node/scripts',
  env:_.extend(process.env, { PATH: process.env.PATH + ':/usr/local/bin' })
});
```

Comment cwd: line no. 4

Until now I don't know what is `process.env.HOME` value but this worked for me.